# Create Wordpress User With Given Username During Import

Tags: wordpress, user

We are trying to have a membership signup page on our WordPress site. The idea is that upon membership creation a user will be created in WordPress.

<strike>So I have a membership sign-up page using a profile that I've created. Almost everything works as I want it except for how the users in WordPress are being created. It is creating the username as a combination of title, first name, and last name.</strike>

I don't have a username field on the profile. There is seemingly no username data point in CiviCRM that I can add to the profile. How can I ask the user to provide a username or change the way it is auto generating them.

I didn't see the option on the profile to create a WordPress user.

**Import Question:**

When I import users as contacts from our Excel sheet it sets the username as title plus first and last name. Is there a way to provide a username on import? Is there a way to map a username column in the CSV?

I'm using the membership role sync plugin in WordPress to sync roles across to the users in WordPress. Ideally I would like to import all the contacts (which will have both current and expired members) and then import memberships as separate. Doing the membership import would create the user, correct? Again, I'd like to be able to define the username here.

Comment: Mike: I have responded to your feature request on GitHub. Let's continue the discussion there and I'll post a canonical answer here when we've resolved this.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out with the help of @Christian Watch.

Christian's plugin [CiviCRM WP Member Sync](https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-member-sync) took care of this. Once a filter was added to allow plugins to handle the username I was able to change the username creation during the membership import to be what I wanted.